# How to calculate steps needed for arrow to fill all given sectors of the clock?

Tags: math

the problem's data are:
Analog clock is dived into 512 even sections, arrow/handle starts its movement at 0° and each tick/step moves it by 4.01°. Arrow/Handle can move only clockwise. What minimum ticks/steps count is needed for arrow/handle to visit all sections of the clock.

I'm trying to write a formula to calculate the count but can't quite wrap my head around it.
Is it possible to do it? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is for programmers, isn't it?
So we can hire our silicon friend to work for us ;)

Full circle is `360*60*60*4=5184000` units (unit is a quarter of angular second)
One step is `4*(4*3600+36) = 57744` units
One section is `4*360*3600/512 = 10125` units  (we use quarters to make this value integer)

```
cntr = set()
an = 0
step = 57744
div = 10125
mod = 5184000
c = 0
while len(cntr) < 512:
    sec = (an % mod) // div
    cntr.add(sec)
    an += step
    c += 1
print(c)

>>804
```

Comment: Due to the nature of this simulation, some of the sections are added more than once and some of the sections aren't visited at all.
Modified `cntr.add(sec)` can be used, adding only if sections haven't been added before.

But the question still remains, is it possible to calculate the count of needed steps beforehand, without running the simulation?

Comment: cntr is `set`, it does not count the same sector again. Theoretical calculation, honestly, is for another site like math.stackexchange

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't recognize Python syntaxis, thought it was pseudo. This simulation works as indented. Thanks for the reference to math.stackexchange, I shall try my luck there too.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I can`t fully answer your question but the following may help:

Dividing the 512 Sections into degree gives you 1,4222° each.
Each round you cover 90 different section when starting between 0°-3.11° and 89° when starting between 3.12°-4.00°

For starting the rounds this gives you a change in starting degree of 0.9° every round except after the fourth, where it is only 0.89°(within the possible range of 0°-4° so all calculated mod 4).

So you have 0.9°->1.8°->2.7°->3.6°->0.49->1.39°...0.08°...

I hope this helps you devloping an algorithm